# Is it possible to add some sort of hook to wget to pre-process HTML returned?

Tags: wget

I want to mirror one of my websites.

Unfortunately, the site is in its *preview mode*, and a GET param must be appended to all URLs in the page for it to continue in its preview mode.

This GET param was added with JavaScript. Obviously, that does not affect `wget`.

Is there a way I can send the returned HTML off to a script to add these myself before `wget` attempts to crawl all the URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. What I understand is that:

- you're retrieving web pages recursively;
- your pages contain internal links;
- following these links leads to a non-existing page, and you would like to rewrite each link to add an extra parameter to the HTTP request.

I don't think you can do that with wget. I suggest using [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) instead. It comes with a script called [`lwp-rget`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lwp-rget) that performs recursive retrievals. There's a line

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
```

Just before this line, add some code to mangle the [URL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aURL) as appropriate, something like

```
$url->query_form($url->query_form, "show_preview" => "yes");
```